# Why do molecules have to first transform to gas before doing a reaction?

Tags: enthalpy, phase

I have to calculate the enthalpy of the reaction
$$\ce{Cs(l) + 1/2I2(s) -> CsI(s)}$$
and the answer is
$$\Delta H_f = \Delta H_{vap}^{\ce{Cs}} + \frac{1}{2}\Delta H_{subl}^{\ce{I2}} + \frac{1}{2}E_{diss}^{\ce{I2}} + I_1^{\ce{Cs}} + E_A^{\ce{I}} + E_N.$$
I can see that the molecules are first put to gas state before creating an ionic bond.

Why does it have to do it ?
In which case do the molecules have to first go in gas state before reacting ?
Is it only in case of ionic bond ?

Notes:

- $E_{diss}$ is the energy of dissociation between the to atoms $\ce{I}$.
- $I_1$ is the energy of first ionisation.
- $E_A$ is the energy of electron affinity.
- $E_N$ is the energy of neutralisation between $\ce{Cs+}$ ans $\ce{I-}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all reactions require vaporization. This process looks like the [Born-Haber cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born-Haber_cycle) for cesium iodide, an exercise in [Hess's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hess%27_Law) usually used to fill in one of the missing values in the cycle that might be hard to measure (usually lattice energy, but not always). The Born-Haber cycle can also be used to drive general chemistry students crazy.

The $E_N$ "energy of neutralization" looks like the [lattice energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_energy), which is **defined** as the enthalpy/energy change accompanying the formation of a solid crystal lattice from the gas phase ions. In your case, the lattice energy of $\ce{CsI}$ is defined as the energy change accompanying the following reaction:

$$\ce{Cs+ (g) + I^- (g) -> CsI(s)}$$

Because the lattice energy is defined for gas phase ions, you need the vaporization enthalpies for this process. Not all reactions require this vaporization step.

Comment: Ok so, it is necessary to vaporize when I want to build a ionic bond right ?
Isn't it weird that there is not the deposition enthalpy of the CsI ?